# Encryption Unsuccessful error

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, encryption

I have an Amazon Kindle Fire 2nd Generation (Tate). [A few years ago I installed the Pacman KitKat Rom](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2355103).

Recently I tried installing a few new roms. However I didn't like any of them because they don't have multi user support. So I decided to reinstall the Pacman KitKat Rom.

I have installed everything correctly, but on startup it says:

*"Encryption Unsuccessful – Encryption was interrupted and can't complete. As a result, the data on your phone is no longer accessible. To resume using your phone, you need to perform a factory reset. When you set up your phone after the reset, you'll have an opportunity to restore any data that was backed up to your Google account."*

It gives the option to reset tablet, but the same error comes up again.

I have tried booting into TeamWin recovery and reinstalling the rom as well as doing a wipe of everything, but the error message persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wipe - though you need to format.
While in TWRP, enter Wipe menu, then select *Format Data* (type yes and confirm); go back, enter *Advanced Wipe* and select everything, then *Swipe to Wipe*.
Reboot to bootloader, then boot recovery, push ROM && install.
This is generally accepted course of action that regular user should do when error in encryption occur(s).