# Nexus 5 in boot loop

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop, twrp, encryption, nexus-5x

I will explain the issue in sequence

1. I was running custom ROM on my Nexus 5.
2. One day the device was stuck in flying colour dot animation and never came out of that
3. I went to recovery mode and cleaned the cache but there was no change
4. I did a complete factory restore.  Nothing got resolved (The USB debugging option got disabled during this :( )
5. I again tried to go to recovery mode. Suddenly TWRP started asking password for decryption. I don't remember enabling encryption and setting a password. I don't even have a screen lock. I trided "default_password" which didn't help.
   [image: twrp welcome message]
6. I press cancel , which redirected to this screen
   [image: after pressing cancel]
7. I selected install option and went to this screen. There was nothing displayed 
   [image: when selected install option]
8. I pressed back and selected ADB sideload and selected clean cache, which also failed with these messages
   [image: ADB sideload screen]
9. I pressed back again and selected mount option and tried to mount system and firmware which again landed in password screen
   [image: selected mount option]
   [image: Asking decryption password for mounting]
10. ADB and fastboot were not able to identify the device when I connected to PC through USB. I can see this message poping up on Windows
    [image: device not recognized by windows]

Please suggest a solution for this

Comment: Can you reboot it into the bootloader and flash a fresh ROM? I'd recommend choosing one that doesn't corrupt your storage this time.

Comment: <a href="https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187021/245102">You should format, not wipe /data while in TWRP</a>, then install ROM.

Comment: @Dan Hulme How can I flash without USB?. Nexus 5 doesn't have SD card also